# Use e1000e network driver instead of tg3

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

On my machine lspci -v shows that my ethernet controller is using tg3. Can I use e1000e instead of tg3. Unloading tg3 module and the load e1000e module is not helping because the eth0 interface remains down after the e1000e is loaded. Please suggest if I am missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Linux, belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com ( or maybe http://superuser.com )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tg3 and e1000e are drivers for different models of ethernet card.  If you want to use e1000e for some reason you'll need to buy a suitable intel Ethernet card.